# How to use custom UICollectionViewCell within Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I don't understand why the custom cell is not recognised in the Storyboard.

**TNTopStoriesCollectionViewController:**

```
static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"TNTopNewsCellItem";

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell *cell = (TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell
    [self preLoadImagesForCategory:_dataStore.fiveTopStories[indexPath.item] andImageView:cell.itemImage];
    return cell;
}
```

I'm using a storyboard for the collectionView:
[image]

And the cell is also correctly pointing to the custom class:
[image]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *itemImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

@end
```

And the correct cell identifier is also used:
[image]

And yet I get this exception within `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
[UICollectionViewCell itemImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

But why please?

**Update:**

I did everything as suggested and am now getting this:
[image]

However it still fails at the same spot. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this cell is called "Collection View Cell" on the *left*, in the hierarchical name listing of objects in the scene, and has not changed to "Top Stories Collection View Cell" suggests that you have *not* actually changed its class in the storyboard to TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell successfully.

(Notice how the collection view controller is listed on the *left* as Top Stories Collection View Controller. The same kind of thing should have happened to the cell.)

What you see on the left should look more like this:

[image]

(Also, the fact that your label outlet is called News Label on the left is suggestive of a problem, since in *code* this label is called "title", and if you've hooked that up correctly I'd expect Xcode to have changed its name to "title" in the listing on the left as well.)

[I have a vague feeling that you may actually have two classes, TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell and TNTopNewsCellItem, and you've confused yourself about them...]

Comment: Perhaps you changed the definition of this class somehow? It might help to delete this scene and start over. It might also be the case that you need to clear the cache for this project.

Comment: I cleared the cache multiple times without luck.  You are right about naming, but thats because I had given `Identity Inspector --> Document -> Label` the value "Collection View Cell".  I have removed it and now it says `TNTopNewsCellItem` and yet nothing works :(

Comment: Right, but I'm saying this whole scene is hosed and needs to be deleted. Delete it, save, quit Xcode, empty the Derived Data folder, open the project again and start over on this scene.

Comment: Also a TNTopNewsCellItem is not a thing (it's just a reuse identifier string). Your class is called TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell, and that is what should be used to name the item on the left if all has gone well. It looks as if IB failed to find this class in your code. Either that or you've got two different classes and you've forgotten which is which! :)

Comment: Thank you. I just everything you said however it still fails on that spot. :( See updated question.

Comment: All I can tell you is that the error means that the storyboard is delivering to you a vanilla UICollectionViewCell and not a TNTopStoriesCollectionViewCell. You could add some logging after your "dequeue" call to confirm this. But I don't have enough info to tell you why that would be.

Comment: It is just barely possible that the problem is caused by an earlier version of the storyboard that is somehow being left in your project. Choose iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings to make sure the existing built app is built cleanly.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  The combination of Reset Content plus removing cell and readding it worked.  However I also needed add the identifier as I had it above in first place. :)  Many Thanks

Comment: Right, with no identifier you'd crash in a whole different way. :)

Answer (score 0):

> In storyboard, there is another way to create Custom
>   CollectionViewCell.That is Separately create the new
>   file(CustomCellCollectionViewCell.h,CustomCollectionViewCell.m and
>   CustomCollectionViewCell.xib) through the IOS->Source->Cocoa Touch
>   Class->SubClass of UICollectionViewCell and give name in Class. After
>   that you can import the the .h of CustomCollectionViewCell and also
>   you need to register that in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
   flowLayout.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
   UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
   [collectionViewSelection registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCollectionCell"];
}
```

Then

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCollectionCell";
   CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. But you are using the classic Xib, instead of Storyboards. Thanks

Comment: No No within storyboard I use this.

Comment: I see what you mean.  So instead of defining the `Header` inside Storyboard you create a separate xib and register it in there. Its possible. Thanks